# visual studio 2010 express linking file in different projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking, dynamic-linking

in visual studio 2010 express edition. i have a project (a static library) called prj1.
 prj1 has codes to create an object obj1.

in another project prj2 which is a dynamic library i have code which intantiates the object by "new obj1" (the code of obj1 is in prj1).

now when i try to build prj2 i get linking errors:

1> when i try to right click on prj2->properties->frameworkk and references if i add prj1 as new reference i get a lot of link errors like MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005:

2> if i do not do step1 above and right click on the solution->properties->project dependencies and then  choose prj1 to depend on the prj2. then i get just get a link error which complains that : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol obj1... unresolved externals.

It would be very kind if someone can help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your options that choose runtime library differ. One project for example links to "multi-threaded debug DLL" and other project to "multi threaded debug". When you try to link the projects to each other then you get multiply defined runtime library symbols.

Comment: both my project has "multi threaded debug". but i still get the 2nd error. are you suggesting i do not do that.

Comment: worked, after making them equal i had to include the add new reference to proj1.

Comment: Better use "multi-threaded debug DLL" for both. You get smaller binaries that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your static library must be found/added to your library directories, and dependency list, too.

Comment: this was not the issue when i had a similar siutation in visual studio 2008. i did not need to add the library directories in 2008. are you suggesting i do that in vs2010 ?